# Recursive function returns segmentation fault

Tags: c, recursion, segmentation-fault, argv

I want to calculate a number to the power `p`, got `Segmentation fault` as a result.
This code is supposed to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int my_power(int nb, int p)
{
    if (nb != 0){
        return nb*my_power(nb, p-1);
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char argv[]){

    printf("%d\n", my_power(5, 3));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: well your argument parsing is completely off. You need to convert argv strings to integers using atoi for instance.  try `printf("%d\n", my_power(atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2])));`

Comment: Hint: when does the recursion stop?

Comment: You never decrement your `nb` thus `nb != 0` never happens, thus program takes up whole stack and dies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to a solution by checking for `p` instead of `nb` and it worked.
I've added conditions for the negative valeus and the 0^0 case.

```
int power(int base, int a) {
    if ( base=0 && a=0){
        return 1;
    }
    if (a!=0){
        return (base * power(base, a-1));
    }else{
        return 1;
        }
}
```

Thank you for the hints.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, your recursion never ends.
Change the base case to **pb<=0** and it will work.